# GTA 5 Need Assistance

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have no missions left on gta 5, I've done all tow truck missions, the epsilon missions(which are side missions).

The last main mission done was "daddy's little girl" and the next mission has Lester offering me a job, but somehow I can't get a hold of Lester or go to his house, like it hasn't been set. What requirements do I need to access that mission?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice. Any new information can simply be added to your existing question using the Edit button.

Comment: Are you saying you're playing as Michael but there is no L where Lester's house is?

Comment: yes I have received the call from him and he is in my contacts sorry im new to this

Answer (score 0):

If you were on the pc version, there is a common bug where the story won't continue and you won't get any more missions, I've had this occur to me and I had to revert to an earlier save. If you have called everyone and there are no markers on the map then you are probably experiencing this bug. You should revert to an earlier save if you have one or if not you might have to start the story again or download a save from a similar point to were you are up to, a quick Google search should help you find one